# How to change java class generic type signature?

Tags: java, spring, generics

I 'll get straight to the point. Here is the problem

I have a class ClassA

```
public class ClassA<GENERICTYPE extends TypeA>
{
    ...
}
```

What I want to achieve is make the `GENERICTYPE` extend a new `TypeB` where `TypeB extends TypeA`

One possible solution is

```
public class ClassB<GENERICTYPE extends TypeB> extends ClassA<GENERICTYPE>
{
    //emtpy
}
```

But doesn't seem to be the right approach.

Any suggestions?

If it makes any difference, I am using Spring 4.

Thanks

Nikos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the right idea, but not quite how you specify it:

```
public class ClassB<T extends TypeB> extends ClassA<T> {

}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I missed that. I ll fix my question. Thanks for answer also.